# Is it possible to run a java program inside a C# on a windows phone?

Tags: java, c#, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-10-mobile

I'm in 2nd year of bachelor and working on my final project which is on the end of 3rd year.. But the project is on Java. I want to make it run in my laptop and on my phone. But I have a Microsoft Lumia 640. And I know how to create apps for my phone just in C#. Is it possible to design a mini software, and run it inside a C# app in my phone?

Comment: xamarin maybe? or is the viceversa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, natively Windows Phone doesn't support Java but you can take a look to [codename one](https://www.codenameone.com/) where in their manifesto says that you will able to make mobile application for any platform only using java.

Comment: there are many posts who say that they do.. but google doesnt show much

Comment: @AltjenB. Mainly because codename one is not used as other alternative such as hybrid frameworks, native programming languages or xamarin

Answer (score 0):

If you habe the java application as a jar lib  you can use ikvm (a jvm for .net) and then you can theoretically run java bin code on the windows phone... you will need to take a look because maybe the issue will be how to deploy that jar to your phone at runtime